# Replace all "=" but not "==" that are not in single quotes with regular expression in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

**Input**

`age=10 and address='a==c=d' and age==100 and abc = 22`

**Expected**

`age = 10 and address='a==c=d' and age==100 and abc  =  22`

**Explanation:**

`age = 10` now has space, `age==100` remains unchanged, `abc = 22` becomes `abc  =  22`, content inside single quotes is not changed

Have similar regular expressions that work for other symbols:
For example ,the below expressions replace `<` but not `<=` that is not in a single quote

```
        joined = joined.replaceAll("<(?![=])(?=(?:[^\\\']*\\\'[^\\\']*\\\')*[^\\\']*$)", " < ");
        joined = joined.replaceAll(">(?![=])(?=(?:[^\\\']*\\\'[^\\\']*\\\')*[^\\\']*$)", " > ");
        #example: age  <=  10 and address='<==c<d' and age==100 age   <    2
```

Getting undesired result when using the same pattern for '='

E.g. Applying `=(?![=])(?=(?:[^\']*\'[^\']*\')*[^\']*$)`

on this string -> `age = 10 and address='a==c=d' and age==100` , the `==` is also matched

May check the result in
[regex101](https://regex101.com/)

Attempted different combinations
the closest I can get so far is
`\b(\s+)?={1}(\s+)?\b`
this matches `=` exactly one time with optional `space` on the sides.
However it targets `=` inside single quotes as well, which is not wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://regex101.com/r/9ySIa2/1

`(?<=[^=])=(?=[^=])(?=(?:[^\']*\'[^\']*\')*[^\']*$)`

`=(?![=])`

has been replaced with

`(?<=[^=])=(?=[^=])`

`=(?![=])` matches an equal sign followed by not an equal sign.  This means that in `==1`, the first `=` is not matched because it's followed by an `=`, but the second is followed by a `1`, so it gets matched.

`(?<=[^=])=(?=[^=])` matches an equal sign, but only if the character before is not an equal sign (`(?<=[^=])` positive lookbehind) as well as if the next character is also not an equal sign (`(?=[^=])` positive lookahead)

Comment: There is no match when the string is `"age=10 and address=a==c=d' and age==100 and abc = 22"`. Perhaps you are assuming there is an even number of single quotes.